# Replacing characters within a string in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, string, char, ionic-framework

Although I've seen similar question's nothing quite answers why this doesn't work, and I'm unaware of an alternative.

I'm making a very simple calculator and when pulling the expression from the string I need to replace symbols such as '×' and '÷' with operators recognized by the eval.

Currently I'm trying to work through the string one character at a time and copy it into a new string, replacing where necessary. It seems that none of the `if` statements checking for characters in the string are ever called and I dont know why.

```
for (var i = 0; i < (expressionPre.length) ; i++) {
    alert(expressionPre[i]);
    if (expressionPre[i] == "÷") {
        expressionPost += "/";
    } else if (expressionPre[i] === '×') {
        expressionPost += "*";
        alert("Finally!");
    } else if (expressionPre[i] == "−") {
        expressionPost += "-";
    } else if (expressionPre[i] % 1 == 0) {
        expressionPost += expressionPre[i];
    }
    alert(expressionPost[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why not using simply the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function: `var expressionPost = expressionPre.replace("÷", "/");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @beaver say, you should use the replace function directly.
this is a function who replace all occurence of text with another one

```js
 function tools_replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
 }
 var str  = "(1 ÷ 2 ÷ 2) × 3 × 3 − 4− 4 + 5 + 5";
 str = tools_replaceAll(str, "÷" , "/" ) ;
 str = tools_replaceAll(str, "×" , "*" ) ;
 str = tools_replaceAll(str, "-" , "-" ) ;
 alert(  str ) ;
```